# Event handling in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, event-handling, vue-component, event-listener

I have a situation where in an event is fired from parent component is being listen to by several child components.

```
e.g.
Parent Component: emit -> "orderReceived"
Child Component1( Tab1): on-> "orderReceived" -> fetch array1 from server
Child Component2( Tab2): on-> "orderReceived" -> fetch array2 from server
```

when both these tabs are opened, everything works fine.
What I'm struggling with is, destroying event listeners on Tab1 and still be able to listen on Tab 2. ( when the tab1 is closed).
Right now if the listeners of Tab1 are destroyed, it disables listeners on Tab 2 as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event must removed from component which was listening not both, You need to use `$off`, to just removed selected event, not all events from the specific component only, not to both

```
const ChildComponent1 = {
  methods:{
    orderReceived(){
      //orderReceived event emit
    }
  },
  created(){
    EventBus.$on('YOURCONTENT', this.orderReceived)
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    EventBus.$off('YOURCONTENT', this.orderReceived)
  }
}
```